# how to style html5 ul links with css?

Tags: html, css

trying to change default color of list items in ul. css style .ul_useful has greyed out a:link just before code block where i thought i had changed color to white, which is what i need.
tried using class in ul, and in list items in ul to no avail. any help appreciated.

first, here is stylesheet styles_p0.css:

```
body{
    padding-top:5rem;
    background:url(/Users/king/proj_0/images/nylon_string_original.JPG);
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: Arial sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    {box-sizing: border-box;}
}

div {
    font-family: Palatino, serif;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

table {
    margin: 1% auto 0 auto;
    border: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 50%;
}

th, td {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

th {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){
    /* styles */
}
/* Smartphones (portrait) ---------- */
@media screen and (max-width: 320px){
    /* styles */
}
/* Smartphones (landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 321px){
    /* styles */
}
/* Tablets, iPads (portrait and landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){
    /* styles */
}
/* Tablets, iPads (portrait) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px){
    /* styles */
}
/* Tablets, iPads (landscape) ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 1024px){
    /* styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 1224px){
    /* styles */
}
/* Large screens ---------- */
@media screen and (min-width: 1824px){
    /* styles */
}

.header_p {
        text-align:center;
        font-family: Arial sans-serif;
        text-shadow:5px 5px 10px #ffffff;
}

.join {
    padding:2px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    text-align: center;
}

.p > div {
        text-align: center;
}

.row > div {
    padding: 2px;

}

.section_d {
        padding: 2px;
        font-family: Palatino, serif;
        text-align:center;
}



.ul_useful {
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
      color: white;
}

/* visited link */
a:visited {
  color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
  color: hotpink;
}

/* selected link */
a:active {
  color: white;
}
}

#footer_p {
    padding-top:2px;
    padding-left:4px;
    padding-right: 2px;
    margin-top: 2%;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:5px 5px 10px #ffffff;
    color: #FFFF00;
}

#Joe { /* image of joe */
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    padding:0px;
    margin-right:2%;
    margin-top:2%;
    margin-bottom:0;
    border:2px solid #ffffff;
}

#why_play {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

here is html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon_nylon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- My styles for project0 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_p0.css">
    <title>Finger Style Guitar Club</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="chart.html">Chart</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item active">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div>
            <h1>Finger Style Guitar Club</h1>
                    <h2>Drop That Pick!</h2>
                    <p class="header_p">It's gonna happen anyway...&#128526;</p>
        </div>
        <section>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col">
                        <h4 id="why_play">Connect with Joe</h3>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a><script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
                            <img id="Joe" src="images/jam_smile_fgc175p.jpg" alt="Joe Mac">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <h4>Useful Links:</h3>
                            <ul class="ul_useful">
                                <li class="ul_useful"><a href="https://www.jazzguitar.be/blog/walking-bass-lines/">Walking Bass Lines for Guitar</a></li>
                                <li class="ul_useful"><a href="https://www.fundamental-changes.com/walking-basslines-on-guitar/">Building Walking Bass Lines</a></li>
                                <li class="ul_useful"><a href="https://www.musicradar.com/tuition/guitars/acoustic-guitar-lessons-walking-basslines-489588">Acoustic Bass Lines</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <footer class="footer">
          <div class="container">
            <p id="footer_p">Copyright &copy; 2020 Joe Mac Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
          </div>
        </footer>
    </section>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: did the below answer helped you to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Changed the `a` color from blue to red, is this what you're asking?

There are couple of issues with code as well:

1. The start and end tag of `<h4>` is incorrect.
2. I see there unwanted code for `table` I am not sure that is used in your code.
3. There is not class called `.ul_useful` in your HTML to render the color, you just defined only in CSS but not used in HTML, you may have to look into that.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 5rem;
  background: url(/Users/king/proj_0/images/nylon_string_original.JPG);
  background-size: cover;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial sans-serif;
  overflow:auto;
  color: #ffffff;
  {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

}

div {
  font-family: Palatino, serif;
  padding: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}

h3 {
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

table {
  margin: 1% auto 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

th {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  color: red;
  /*changed from blue to red*/
}


/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ---------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  /* styles */
}


/* Smartphones (portrait) ---------- */

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  /* styles */
}


/* Smartphones (landscape) ---------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 321px) {
  /* styles */
}


/* Tablets, iPads (portrait and landscape) ---------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
  /* styles */
}


/* Tablets, iPads (portrait) ---------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  /* styles */
}


/* Tablets, iPads (landscape) ---------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  /* styles */
}


/* Desktops and laptops ---------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 1224px) {
  /* styles */
}


/* Large screens ---------- */

@media screen and (min-width: 1824px) {
  /* styles */
}

.header_p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial sans-serif;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #ffffff;
}

.join {
  padding: 2px;
  margin-top: -20px;
  text-align: center;
}

.p>div {
  text-align: center;
}

.row>div {
  padding: 2px;
}

.section_d {
  padding: 2px;
  font-family: Palatino, serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.ul_useful {
  /* unvisited link */
  a:link {
    color: white;
  }
  /* visited link */
  a:visited {
    color: green;
  }
  /* mouse over link */
  a:hover {
    color: hotpink;
  }
  /* selected link */
  a:active {
    color: white;
  }
}

#footer_p {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 5px 5px 10px #ffffff;
  color: #FFFF00;
}

#Joe {
  /* image of joe */
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

#why_play {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon_nylon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
  <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
  <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- My styles for project0 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles_p0.css">
  <title>Finger Style Guitar Club</title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Home</a>
    <div class="container">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="about.html">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="chart.html">Chart</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <h1>Finger Style Guitar Club</h1>
    <h2>Drop That Pick!</h2>
    <p class="header_p">It's gonna happen anyway...&#128526;</p>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h4 id="why_play">Connect with Joe</h4>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/share?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw" class="twitter-share-button" data-show-count="false">Tweet</a>
          <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
          <img id="Joe" src="images/jam_smile_fgc175p.jpg" alt="Joe Mac">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <h4>Useful Links:</h4>
          <ul class="ul_useful">
            <li class="ul_useful"><a href="https://www.jazzguitar.be/blog/walking-bass-lines/">Walking Bass Lines for Guitar</a></li>
            <li class="ul_useful"><a href="https://www.fundamental-changes.com/walking-basslines-on-guitar/">Building Walking Bass Lines</a></li>
            <li class="ul_useful"><a href="https://www.musicradar.com/tuition/guitars/acoustic-guitar-lessons-walking-basslines-489588">Acoustic Bass Lines</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container">
        <p id="footer_p">Copyright &copy; 2020 Joe Mac Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </section>
</body>
```